# If statement not working as intended (Python)

Tags: python, if-statement

This code I wrote for my study on if statements in Python doesn't seem to work properly since it asks the same question twice after the first one being asked.

```
Identity = input("Who are you? ")

if Identity == "Jane":
    print("You must be John's sister.")
elif Identity != "John":
    print("My database doesn't recognise you. Who are you I wonder...")
elif Identity == "John":
    if input("What is your last name? ") != "Travolta":
        print("False! John's name is Travolta and not " + input("What is your last name? ") + ".")
    elif input("How old are you? ") == "Travolta":
        if input("How old are you? ") != "20 yo":
            print("False! John is 20 yo and not " + input("How old are you? ") + ".")
        elif input("How old are you? ") == "20 yo":
            print("You must in fact be John!")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if input("What is your last name? ") != "Travolta":
    print("False! John's name is Travolta and not " + input("What is your last name? ") + ".")
```

Here you aren't storing the value of the input and printing it. You are asking the person to input again "what is your last name?".

Do something like

```
last_name = input("What is your last name? ")
```

and use it instead of the input() in the if statement.

Here I am putting the snippet in the way I would've done it.

```
identity = input("Who are you? ")

if identity == "Jane":
    print("You must be John's sister.")
elif identity != "John":
    print("My database doesn't recognise you. Who are you I wonder...")
elif identity == "John":
    last_name = input("What is your last name? ")
    if last_name != "Travolta":
        print("False! John's last name is Travolta and not " + last_name + ".")
    else:
        age = input("How old are you? ")
        if age != "20 yo":
            print("False! John is 20 yo and not " + age + ".")
        else:
            print("You must in fact be John!")
```

It is working properly for every possibility. Examples:

[image: Jane input]

[image: John full]

Comment: Hey! Thank you for answering. I've already tried doing that however, and the problem I've encountered with that method is that it still asks the follow-up questions even if I answer "Jane" which isn't what I want :/ I'm guessing putting the input prompt as a variable as you've suggested also makes it so it asks the question. Sorry if I explained it poorly, I'm on mobile currently but I will try to make it clearer if needed :)

Comment: Aaah thank you for showing the entire code. I wrote the last name and age input at the beginning of the code along with identity which is why the other questions were still being asked even with the wrong input. Thank you so much for helping me, I've been stuck on this for a few days!